# Cannot save or exit in sudoeditor

Tags: command-line, server, sudo, text-editor

I am new using sudoeditor and I just want to edit `sources.list` file and then exit. However, after editing the file, I cannot save or exit. First I press ESC and then try to type the activated cursor at the bottom line, :q or :wq. However, it does not work (I cannot type this bottom line, it gives [ESC : unbound] and similar messages).

I also tried some functşion keys e.g. F4 and F3, or Ctrl + X, but unfortunately cannot exit with & without saving. So, how can I do this?

Comment: Which text editor are you using? Vim? Nano?

Comment: I use the default editor on the PuTTY command line (there is a line saying Jove editor but I am not sure).

Comment: [Looks like](https://ts.vcu.edu/askit/research-math-science/unix-for-researchers-at-vcu/unix-text-editors/jove-a-text-editor/#Saving_and_Exiting) you’ll need to do [Ctrl]+[\\] to save and exit.

Comment: I have the same problem, using VMware, I tried to switch keyboard layout, helped a little bit, but it's still stuck sometimes.